# Paste id into href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href

I have a lot of streams.

```
<a id="stream1" href="http://server/stream1/parameters">name_1</a>
<a id="stream2" href="http://server/stream2/parameters">name_2</a>
...
<a id="stream99" href="http://server/stream99/parameters">name_99</a>
```

I want to hide `"http://server/stream99/parameters"`

How to do a function to paste "id" into href

eg:

```
<a id="stream1" href="#">name_1</a>
```

using something like

```
function somefunction(a) {
   document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = '<a href="http://server/'+id+'/parameters">';
}
```

Javascript or jquery will make the link and paste the "id".

Or perhaps I can somehow use a different method to hide links?

Comment: it's a little bit unclear what you're asking. can you clarify

Comment: Not really sure what you want to achieve

Comment: Clarify please !

Comment: Also note, document.getElementById('a') >> the id is not 'a' but 'stream1', 'stream2' etc..

Comment: totally unclear question - describe exactly what is the point here. We'll be glad to help

Comment: @PaoloFalomo totally clear question. Use your imagination :)

Comment: use.htaccess redirection instead

Answer (score 2):

Like this - do note that this is easy to decipher by inspecting the code.
Alternatively use a server redirect and just send some encrypted ID

```js
$(function() {
  $(".stream").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    location = "http://server/" + this.id + "/parameters";
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="stream1" class="stream" href="#">name_1</a><br>
<a id="stream2" class="stream" href="#">name_2</a><br>
<a id="stream3" class="stream" href="#">name_3</a><br>
<a id="stream4" class="stream" href="#">name_4</a><br>
```